# Migrating old SQL Servers

Tags: sql-server-2012, sql-server-2016

I found myself in a rather complex situation and need some advice...

We are moving our complete environment to a new Server and virtual servers.

I have reached a point where i found out that some of the old Servers (2000 and 2003) that I wanted to dispose contain Databases which are required for some of our (old but essential) software packages. These contain hardcoded data about these old servers and cannot be altered, so i'm stuck with them.

I wonder if there is a way to create a virtual name/path or sth on the new server, so i could move the old databases there, but while this is done, the software still needs to recognize them by their old name. For example - old database in on old server STHSRV1/name1 or STHSRV2/name2, and i want both of these to be on the new server, but accessible through their old names.

Is this even possible?

Thanks everyone

Comment: Well, there is one DIRTY way that may help you. You can add an entry into the LMHOST file on your application server with the IP of the new server, and what name you want the IP to resolve to. Or, after building the new SQL servers, you can create an DNS CNAME record that's the same name as the old servers that point to the new ones. This situation is why I've always used CNAMES for the underlying connections that applications / developers use. If I have to move an instance or a server it's completely transparent to them. They have no clue that real server name is or where it's located.

Answer (score 1):

[Would creating an alias be any use to you?](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/create-or-delete-a-server-alias-for-use-by-a-client?view=sql-server-ver15#:~:targetText=To%20create%20an%20alias&targetText=In%20the%20Server%20box%2C%20type,Pipe%20Name%2C%20or%20Connection%20String.)